# working on python small application to perform sum of 2 integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def numberinput(num1, num2):
    try:
        int(num1)
        int(num2)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def add(num1, num2):
    return int(num1) + int(num2)

def main():
    import sys
    var1 = input("enter your first number")
    var2 = input("enter your first number")
    if(numberinput(var1, var2)):
        print(add(var1,var2))
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        return
main()
```

working on python small application to perform sum of 2 integer along with validation that integer must not exceed the actual size of byte-coded integers, i.e. min 00000000 and max 11111111 in Base 2 or min 0 and max 255 in Base 10 for positive integers

Comment: What's the question? Do you need help checking if two variables are smaller than 256?

Comment: want to check both input  that integer must not exceed the actual size of byte-coded integers, i.e. min 00000000 and max 11111111 in Base 2 or min 0 and max 255 in Base 10

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I check whether an int is between the two numbers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13628791)

Comment: What do you keep saying "actual byte coded integer"? Python integer types are arbitrarily sized. As long as you have memory and address space, you can have bigger integers all you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `number` input function should check for four conditions. So, its body should be something like

```
return num1<255 and num1>0 and num2<255 and num2>0
```

In a more python-specific style, you could write

```
return 0<num1<255 and 0<num2<255
```

Comment: that's it..? i mean there isn't need to convert into byte-code and then check it?

Comment: checking max 11111111 in binary or max 255 in decimal is equivalent. So you only need to check one or the other. Decimal is easier and more readable. Unless it's homework, in that case depends on what the assignments says

Comment: • The program must check the input data for the data type permitted and the data value limitations (the value of the integer must not exceed the actual size of byte-coded integers, i.e. min 00000000 and max 11111111 in Base 2 or min 0 and max 255 in Base 10 for positive integers, min 10000000 and max 01111111 in Base 2 or min -128 and max +127 in Base 10 for signed integers)

this is the actual requirement

Comment: @Ali: I'm afraid the assignment is not correct. This could be done in eg, C or java. But in python there is no such thing. There is only one integer type, and it can have infinitely large or small values.

Answer (score 0):

Change your validation function as follows:

```
 def numberinput(num1, num2):
      return 0<=num1<=255 and 0<=num2<=255
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an old piece of code that you could use as reference to help with your minimum maximum issue.

```
cheese_max = 112.0
cheese_min = 0.16
price_per_one = 0.75

order_amount = input('How much cheese would you like?: ')

if float(order_amount) < cheese_min:
    print('Invalid Entry: Please order more than our minimum of 0.75 units.')
elif float(order_amount) > cheese_max:
    print('Invalid Entry: Please order less than our maximum of 112.0 units.')
else:
    print('That will be',float(order_amount)*price_per_one)
```

If you put this in a forever loop (while True:), after changing it to meet your min of 0 and max of 11111111 and have appropriate responses to your purpose, then it will only accept valid entries that meet your min and max requirements.

I'm not truly sure what you are trying to ask, there isn't really a question in your post. But if your looking for help on your min max condition, this should help.